# Find all polynomials that pass through (1,1) and (3,3)

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ of the form $f(t)=a+bt+ct^2$ that pass through the points $(1,1)$ and $(3,3)$ and where $f'(2)=3$.

I came up with the following equations:

$$a+b+c=1$$

$$a+3b+9c=3$$

$$b+4c=3$$

But whenever I try to solve for a, b, and c using reduced echelon form, I find that the system is inconcsistent. Can someone please help me here?

Comment: The system you've written out appears correct based on the given conditions, and it's definitely inconsistent. So it doesn't look like any such polynomials exist...

Answer (score 1):

The system is inconsistent, therefore such polynomial does not exist.

There's nothing surprising about it - consider, for example, second order polynomial $f$ with $f(x_1)=0$, $f(x_2)=0$, $x_1\neq x_2$. Then surely $f'(\tfrac{x_1+x_2}2)=0$, so any other choice of $f'(\tfrac{x_1+x_2}2)$ would be inconsistent.

Comment: +1. And I only fixed the trivial typo because I assumed that I was proofreading my answer, not yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have found yourself that such a polynomial does not exist, and what you have done is completely sufficient to solve the problem.

If the result should surprise you, then consider the function $g(t)=f(t)-t$. $g$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ with $g(1)=g(3)=0$. So you probably know that $g$ has an extremum exactly in the middle of $1$ and $3$, i.e. $g'(2)=0$. It follows that $f'(2)=1$ (and not $=3$), which you have also found using the system of linear equations.